# Input field set to responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have small responsive issues. In div have maximize and minimize option with google map. Customized input field added with in the div. the point is:

```
1.My div is normal size the input field showing correct position

2.When i maximize the div input field is not responsive
```

See the attached image for reference.

Image before maximize:

[image]

Image after maximize:

[image]

This code added my self

```css
position: absolute;
margin: 1px 0;
padding: 0 3px;
right: 4%;
top: 11%;
color: #000 !important;
border: 1px solid #2B9089;
border-radius: 0px !important;
z-index: 9;
width: 125px;
```

Comment: Set parent div to relative, and then other div to absolute, and you can position it perfectly within the parent whether maximised or not.

Comment: Create a wrapper div that is full width... ie. 100vw, 100vh and set it to relative positioning. Then you're search field, set to absolute, and position where you need it.  This should get you closer to what you need.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also explain _how_ it is not response, and how it _should_ look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try using percentual width. In you css file do something like this.

```
input.my-text{
  width:30%
}
```

if the margin is an issues as well you can use the same method like:

```
input.my-text{
  margin-rigth:5%
}
```

Seen your edit try this:

```
position: absolute;
margin: 1px 0;
padding: 0 3px;
right: 4%;
top: 11%;
color: #000 !important;
border: 1px solid #2B9089;
border-radius: 0px !important;
z-index: 9;
width: 5%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You sholuld keep the `input-search` & `search-icon` both in the same parent div using css `position:relative;`. This will definitely control your search-input according to search-icon as you want like:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <input name="" type="text" placeholder="search" />
    <div>Search-icon</div>
</div>
```